# How do I install the ActiveDirectory Powershell module in windows 8.1?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-8.1

I'm trying to use the ActiveDirectory module on a Surface Pro running Windows 8.1, however under Programs and Features | Turn Windows features on or off, it seems that RSAT is no longer listed there. I searched around and not only is a search on this topic flooded with hits for Windows 7, but even the technet article regarding the ActiveDirectory module in 8.1 links to Server 2012 when investigating installation.

Who moved my cheese?

Answer (score 5):

Only servers have RSAT pre-installed. You need to install RSAT before you can activate it on a client OS.

RSAT for 8.1 is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296)